# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't ask for login password anymore after suspend

Tags: suspend, lock-screen

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 (kernel 5.16.0).

Long time it used to work normally, but recently it doesn't ask me password after I suspend the machine anymore.

Checked in `Settings->Privacy->Screen Lock` , everything is turned on (`Lock Screen on Suspend` is on).

Could this relate to timing/signal of monitors ? I have 3 monitors connected to my graphics card through 1 DVI, and 2 HDMI.

Any suggestion to fix this problem?

Comment: I'd suggest checking your provided details; 20.04.3 would imply you're near a year behind on security fixes & patches (*if not more*), and 5.16 is not a *supported* kernel for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. (You can view [20.04.4 release annoucement](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/02/25/ubuntu-20-04-4-lts-released/) to see when 20.04.4 ISO was released, but installed systems upgraded in the weeks before that date, and a 20.04 system hasn't reported 20.04.4 for some time too).  Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: @guiverc thanks for providing info. I do understand I use non-supported kernel version as I manually upgrade myself. But it has been worked for quite long time with such setup. So you imply that I should not ask question regarding to Ubuntu whose setups are not officially supported? Also I don't get why you need to ask whether I'm using Ubuntu as I'm saying I'm using but it might not fit into your definition.

Comment: A Ubuntu 20.04 system if upgraded would **not** report itself as 20.04.3 unless your looked back before 20.04.4 released; OR you have problems & haven't applied security fixes/patches since before 20.04.4, OR you're using a Ubuntu based system that was built using older Ubuntu packages; ie. it's the last possibly that my last "*Are you using Ubuntu?*" relates to.  It's also possible the 20.04.3 was what you installed & not what you're now running, but we're limited to details you provide. Your usage of an *unsupported* kernel didn't worry me, except it added to the *something is wrong* 20.04.3

Comment: FYI:  If you install a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system, using 20.04, 20.04.1, 20.04.2, 20.04.3 media... and apply all upgrades... the system is always *focal* (ie. 20.04) and will upgrade with applied patches to the latest current system, ie. all of 20.04, 20.04.1, 20.04.2, 20.04.3, 20.04.4, or 20.04.5 installs would currently report themselves as 20.04.5 after fixes/patches are applied.  The installs made using ISOs that default to GA kernel stack will all still run the GA kernel, but those using the HWE kernel stack will now be using the latest HWE kernel...

Comment: FYI:  A Ubuntu based system such as Linux Mint can report the incorrect detail, as its not a Ubuntu system and just Ubuntu based.. with changes to the software stack (ie. use of runtime *adjustments* as they very much rely on Ubuntu packages they cannot control).  To maintain stability, they have (*to varying amounts depending on release*) had installs default to not upgrade all packages; which is why a 20.04.3 based Linux Mint always reports with outdated detail... but that's a Ubuntu based system & not a Ubuntu product...

Comment: @guiverc Thank you very much. I manually upgrade the kernel, and didn't use `apt` way of upgrading with fear of breaking something as it upgrades all stuff across the board. That makes sense, and something might break there recently although I've used it for long with this setup and wonder why it has to break now. I'll try something. Thanks again!

Comment: FYI: If you're not applying fixes, that **would explain** the 20.04.3 which I mentioned in the possibilities (*first item*), but that also means your system would be unsafe online etc.  You can *hold* specific packages so they won't upgrade, allowing you to upgrade everything (that's not held or impacted by what you've held), which is far safer than not applying any security fixes to your system where used online or on networks.  The lack of upgrades (*plus testing kernel*) does mean your system is non-standard which makes it harder for us to help though.